# Search the internet for js library reference

Tags: javascript

I was hoping to find examples for where threex.planets.js library is used.  Is there a search engine that would return the site if it contained the code reference in a script tag.

```
<script src=threex.planets.js></script>
```

---EDIT
Can you let me know why you have down voted this question?  I will modify the question or remove it if it is not appropriate.  Some feedback would be good.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I didn't downvote you but I have an explanation: Question about asking for a tool, online library etc. don't belog here - that's why you might get downvoted.. Please read this article on [what topics are allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job but requires payment
https://publicwww.com/

This also does it but is not returning much.
https://nerdydata.com/search?query=%22threex.planets.js%22